# Getting Values from Excel Table on Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, xlsread

I've been trying to simulate a chemical reactor on Matlab. For this to work I need to be able to get some values from excel tables with thermodynamic properties. Each table is for a chemical species and the first row is always the temperature.

I would like to input the temperature so that Matlab would search the temperature column for the value and return, for example, the associated enthalpy.

I used xlsread to load the tables as matrices but I am having trouble to tell Matlab what to do next.

I've been told to try

> [row, ~] = find(temp<=data(:,2));  %temp is the given temperature

but this just returns me

> row = 1, 2, ...

I would also like to be able to handle intermediate temperatures that are not explicit in the table, it could be some kind of interpolation or just getting the nearest value.

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: For starters if you want to find the row when the temperature equals a given value then use == in place of <=. For interpolation, look up the `interp1` function in MATLAB.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've already tried with == and it returns "row =

   Empty matrix: 0-by-1"

Comment: You'll need to share some data. Write some toy example code and post it here...